# Visual Source Safe 2005 Remote Access

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-sourcesafe

I want to let VSSDB accessed via internet (not LAN) from one machine to another.

**Update I**
Thanks for reply but it doesn't. It's saying something failed to enforce SSL requirement on IIS. VSS web services would be disabled on this machine....

**Update II**
Is it possible to connect it after establishing VPN? how

Comment: Good luck...I hope you have a good book to read while SourceSafe does...anything.

Comment: I only opened this question so that I could implore you to stop using VSS

Comment: I had a very bad experience with VSS corrupting a database accessed through a VPN accessed over the Internet. Good Luck, and it's probably time you upgraded to a real source control system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thanks for reply but it doesn't. It's
>   saying something failed to enforce SSL
>   requirement on IIS. VSS web services
>   would be disabled on this machine....

I had the same problem with the VSS internet plugin, turned out that my certificate was installed/trusted in my personal store and not the local computer store.  When VSS attempts to set this up it attempts to contact "https://servernamethatyouspecify" as the local system account.  In my case I was using a self-signed certificate that was not installed/trusted in the local computer store but instead just the personal store of my user account so this request would fail with the security warning saying that this certificate is not trusted.

To make a long story short, just reinstall your certificate but specify the option to 'show physical stores' and be sure you import it into the "Trusted Root Certificates" -> "Local Computer" store.

Overall VSS is a pain to configure/setup, especially the internet plugin and definitely slow for large projects, however if its all you've got the internet plugin does work fine for small projects.  I've used SourceOffSite and it worked pretty great while we had it, managing keys can be a pain but pretty easy to setup.

I'm sure you can use VSS over a VPN via file shares too but I'd imagine that'd be an even slower option with the overhead of using file shares over a vpn.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you're serious about using SourceSafe over a wide area network, you should look into various proxy solutions that are available (though not free), such as:

- [SourceOffSite](http://www.sourcegear.com/sos/)
- [SourceAnywhere](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/SAW_Overview.aspx)
- [VSS Remoting](http://www.sourceremoting.com/)

They improve the speed (and supposedly reliability) of VSS over a WAN using caching and more efficient wire protocols.

They aren't particularly cheap, but the one time I had to use VSS, it was via a remote link and it was supremely painful (unusable, really) without this. I can't remember if I used SourceOffSite or SourceAnywhere.